# (fast_executemany = True) Error "[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification (0) (SQLExecute)')"

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc, executemany

I'm using (executemany) function from pyodbc to populate data into an mssql database. This is my code:

```
def populate_database(conn):
    tuples = [
        ('2020-04-13 00:50:42', 'AirShoppingRQ', 'ALEY', '2020-05-23', '', '', 'BRU-BLQ', ''),     
        ('2020-04-13 00:50:43', 'AirShoppingRQ', 'ALEY', '2021-01-23', '', '', 'LIS-STO', '')
    ]
    query_string = 'INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    #cursor.fast_executemany = True
    cursor.executemany(query_string, tuples)
    cursor.commit()
```

It works fine, but if I uncomment the line `cursor.fast_executemany = True`, then I got the following error:

```
('22018', '[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification (0) (SQLExecute)')
```

The following is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable](
  [field1] [datetime] NULL,
  [field2] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [field3] [varchar](20) NULL,
  [field4] [datetime] NULL,
  [field5] [datetime] NULL,
  [field6] [varchar](20) NULL,
  [field7] [varchar](40) NULL,
  [field8] [varchar](40) NULL
)
```

Is there something wrong with the formats? What am I missing when using `cursor.fast_executemany = True`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to convert all empty strings to None values in the tuples. This doesn't only apply to `datetime` fields.

```
tuples = [(a, *(b if b else None for b in rest)) for a, *rest in tuples]
```

Answer (score 7):

With `fast_executemany = False` (the default), pyodbc sends one INSERT per row and passes the parameter values directly through to SQL Server. When SQL Server encounters an empty string as a parameter value for a `datetime` column the value is interpreted as `1900-01-01 00:00:00`.

With `fast_executemany = True`, pyodbc packs all of the parameter values into a binary structure called a *parameter array* and passes that along with the SQL command text, essentially performing the INSERT of all rows in a single step. However, the SQL Server ODBC Driver does not make the same assumption as T-SQL regarding an empty string for a `datetime` column, so you get the error.

> [22018] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid character value for cast specification (0) (SQLExecute)

TL;DR: It is possible to pass an empty string as a parameter value for a `datetime` column if you are using `fast_executemany = False`, but not if you are using `fast_executemany = True`.

Comment: What is solution to use fast_executemany = True and still be able to insert empty into date column??

Comment: Convert empty strings to `None` values and they will be inserted into the database as NULL.

Comment: Could you please tell me how I can convert empty strings to None on a data frame?

Comment: @harsha87 - Please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), showing what you have tried and why it doesn't work.