# How to insert mm/dd/yyyy strings into a SQL Server datetime column using fast_executemany?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, pyodbc

I am querying data from BQ. I have to insert it to SQL Server 2008.

pseudocode:

```
# get results from bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()
result = client.query(sql).result()

# create parametrized insert sql statement

sql = 'INSERT INTO [SANDBOX].[dbo].[table_stg] VALUES ((?),(?),(?),(?),(?),(?),(?),(?),(?),(?))'

data = [(2016, 'STRING', 'STRING', 'STRING', 'STRING', 'STRING', INT, 'STRING', '09/28/2015', '09/25/2016'), 
(2016, 'STRING', 'STRING', 'STRING', 'STRING', 'STRING', INT, 'STRING', '09/28/2015', '09/25/2016')]

# target table schema

[varchar](50) NULL,
[varchar](50) NULL,
[varchar](50) NULL,
[varchar](50) NULL,
[varchar](50) NULL,
[varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[int] NULL,
[varchar](50) NULL,
[datetime] NULL,
[datetime] NULL


# insert into sql server with fast_executemany

cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany(sql, data)
conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

So when I run cursor.executemany(sql, data) with cursor.fast_executemany = True, I receive error:

> Invalid character value for cast specification.

> String data, right truncation: length 44 buffer 20, HY000

The code works perfectly without cursor.fast_executemany = True, yet it executes each insert with single commit meaning 8 hours to transfer 2 milion rows.

Thanks in advance for help.
Also, if there is some filtering mechanism I could sue to split into fast_execute and normal execute I would be super gratefull.

**EDIT:**
edited the question as per comments

Comment: Why have you tagged both SQL Server and BigQuery? They're completely different products.

Comment: Because I get the results from BigQuery by
>client = bigquery.Client()
>result = client.query(query).result()
And maybe thats valid to solving my problem.

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61204788/2144390

Comment: Thanks, thats a good read, I already tackled issues with empty columns and datetime. 
The only problem (i think) I have is with double quotes surrounding strings with single quotes inside as some kind of bq apoi - python - tsql 2008 conclict. Or maybe something else/more.

Comment: Single quotes within a string parameter value will not be a problem for a well-formed parameterized INSERT query, e.g., `crsr.executemany("INSERT INTO my_table (my_column) VALUES (?)", [("my'problem",), ("what'ever",)])`. Consider adding a [mcve] that can replicate the issue.

Comment: Edited my question as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61204788/2144390) illustrates how `fast_executemany = True` affects the way that empty string parameters are interpreted for `datetime` columns. With `fast_executemany = False`, empty strings are interpreted as `1900-01-01 00:00:00`. With `fast_executemany = True`, empty string parameters cause the "Invalid character value for cast specification" error.

The same appears to be true for `aa/bb/yyyy` string parameters. That format is potentially ambiguous (Is it `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`?) and SQL Server makes assumptions under `fast_executemany = False` that it does not make under `fast_executemany = True`.

This does not throw an error for a column defined as `d1 [datetime]`

```py
cursor.fast_executemany = False
cursor.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO [SANDBOX].[dbo].[table_stg] (d1) VALUES (?)",
    [("09/28/2015",)]
)
```

but this fails

```py
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO [SANDBOX].[dbo].[table_stg] (d1) VALUES (?)",
    [("09/28/2015",)]
)
```

However, this works:

```py
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO [SANDBOX].[dbo].[table_stg] (d1) VALUES (?)",
    [("2015/09/28",)]
)
```

So, either reformat the strings to `yyyy/mm/dd` or parse them into a `datetime` object

```py
cursor.fast_executemany = True
cursor.executemany(
    "INSERT INTO [SANDBOX].[dbo].[table_stg] (d1) VALUES (?)",
    [(datetime.datetime.strptime("09/28/2015", "%m/%d/%Y"),)]
)
```

Comment: Thanks Gord for this detailed answer. I am testing it right now. Can you recommend me some reading material so I could create a data validator compliant for fast_executemany?